# Finding cumulative value of to par for each player

Tags: r

I am trying to find out the cumulative to par score for each player by round, (to par score--score minus par for the hole).

```
load(url(
   "https://www.stat.osu.edu/~vqv/4194/data/masters2011-untidy.rda"
 ))

rounds <- list(round1, round2, round3, round4)
names(rounds) <- 1:4
all_rounds <- bind_rows(rounds, .id = 'round')

scorecard <- all_rounds %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = '1':'18', names_to = 'hole', values_to = 'score') %>% 
  mutate(round = as.integer(round), hole = as.integer(hole)) %>% 
  select(player, round, hole, score)

topar <- scorecard %>% 
  left_join(course, by = "hole") %>% 
  mutate(to_par = score - par) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative = cumsum(to_par))
```

Comment: Please state your problem? Did you fail to do what you wanted to do?

Comment: I am trying to find the cumulative to par score (score minus par for the hole) for all players in the tournament by round and hole.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```r
library(tidyverse)
load(url(
  "https://www.stat.osu.edu/~vqv/4194/data/masters2011-untidy.rda"
))

rounds <- list(round1, round2, round3, round4)
names(rounds) <- 1:4
all_rounds <- bind_rows(rounds, .id = 'round')

scorecard <- all_rounds %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = '1':'18', names_to = 'hole', values_to = 'score') %>% 
  mutate(round = as.integer(round), hole = as.integer(hole)) %>% 
  select(player, round, hole, score)

topar <- scorecard %>% 
  left_join(course, by = "hole") %>% 
  mutate(to_par = score - par) %>% 
  group_by(player, round) %>%
  summarise(to_par = sum(to_par))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'player'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
  
topar
#> # A tibble: 296 × 3
#> # Groups:   player [99]
#>    player         round to_par
#>    <chr>          <int>  <int>
#>  1 Aaron Baddeley     1      3
#>  2 Aaron Baddeley     2     -2
#>  3 Aaron Baddeley     3      2
#>  4 Aaron Baddeley     4      2
#>  5 Adam Scott         1      0
#>  6 Adam Scott         2     -2
#>  7 Adam Scott         3     -5
#>  8 Adam Scott         4     -5
#>  9 Alex Cejka         1      0
#> 10 Alex Cejka         2     -1
#> # … with 286 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You provide me with a new aspect to figure it out, thank you!